# Wildcard query doesn't work as expected on Elastic Search server

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

If I search documents containing status code 200 I get an expected result, but when I search documents containing 20 I get nothing !? I thought wildcard query is sth like SQL's " LIKE '%search%' ". This is just an example and I have the same problem with anothers (string) fields.

Does anyone know why I have this problem and how can I get what I want - SQL's " LIKE '%search%' behavior?

Indexes I search in are automatically created by Logstash.

Here is a part of a query I send:

```
"wildcard": {
    "statusCode": {
        "wildcard": "20",
        "boost": 1.0
    }
}
```

Here is a part of the mapping:

```
"mappings": {
    "doc": {
        ...
        "properties": {
            ...
            "statusCode": {
                "type": "text",
                "norms": false,
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only possible wildcards for the `wildcard` query are `*` or `?`, where did you see that you could use parenthesis?

Comment: I put them because I send both 200 and 20. I'll remove them now for sake of clarity

Comment: Then if you stick with `wildcard` you should specify `20*` or `20?`, otherwise you can use a `prefix` query and simply specify `20`.

Comment: This helps, but I have similar problem I've just described above. TY

Comment: I think the original problem is solved, and the update should belong to a new question.

Comment: I put the update to a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51968671/wildcard-doesnt-work-as-expected-when-querying-by-more-than-a-word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stick with a `wildcard` query you should specify `20*` or `20?`...

```
"wildcard": {
    "statusCode": {
        "wildcard": "20*",
        "boost": 1.0
    }
}
```

or

```
"wildcard": {
    "statusCode": {
        "wildcard": "20?",
        "boost": 1.0
    }
}
```

...otherwise you can use a [`prefix` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) and simply specify `20`

```
"prefix": {
    "statusCode": {
        "value": "20",
        "boost": 1.0
    }
}
```